# ODOO XMLRPC calling custom method which create a record on the same model

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

ODOO(V11) XMLRPC calling on custom model method (test) is through an error if a create method is uncommitted and client expect "self" as argument. (I am using python)

```
    class DataParser(models.Modle):
          _name = "data.parser"
         test_a: fields.Char()
         test_b: fields.Char()

         @api.one
         def test(self):
             obj = self.env['data.parser'].create({'test_a':"test a", 'test_b': "Test B "})
    
            return True
```

Client XMLRPC

```
   url = 'http://localhost:8069'
   db = 'test'
   username = 'admin'
   password = 'admin'

   logging.info("url {}, db {}".format(url, db))

   common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url), allow_none=True)
   print(common.version())
   val  = common.login(db, username, password)

  uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

  models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
  val = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, "data.parser", "test", ["self"])
```

Error
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)\npsycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "test_b" of relation "data_parser" does not exist\nLINE 1: INSERT INTO "data_parser" ("id", "test_b", "test_a

Answer (score 0):

Change field declaration to:

```
test_a = fields.Char()
test_b = fields.Char()
```

When you called `test` method you passed `test` as the first parameter in the place of the `id`, odoo will evaluate it to the following recordset:

```
data.parser('self',)
```

Calling the `create` method using that record set will not raise an error and the new created record will be returned. No error will be raised.

When we try to call the create method with an unknown field, we get the following error in the log:

```
data.parser.create() includes unknown fields: field_name
```

Answer (score 0):

We can send id in args parameter in rpc method!

Like this, I have used in flutter:
`Future<dynamic> backToDraft(int id) { return Constants.odooRpc!.callKw({ 'model': 'account.payment', 'method': 'action_draft', 'args': [id], 'kwargs': {} }); }`